# Deleting Excel cells based on a text string (current code not working)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove all cells in my spreadsheet that have the word TOTAL in them. My current VBA code:

```
Sub Delete_Rows()
  Dim RNG As Range, cell As Range, del As Range
  Set RNG = Intersect(Range("A1:A5000"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
  For Each cell In RNG
  If (cell.Value) = "TOTAL" _
  Then
  If del Is Nothing Then
  Set del = cell
  Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
  End If
  End If
  Next cell
  On Error Resume Next
  del.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

This isn't working, and I can't understand why. Sorry I am being so vague, but clearly something obvious is eluding me.

Thanks

Comment: ... It works for me just the way you had it posted... It only looks in Column A, though, is that what you wanted??

Comment: Yes I just wanted Column A. That is strange. Let me poke around a bit more and get back to you.

Comment: Okay. The code does remove all cells that only contain "TOTAL" and nothing else. However, other cells (such as "TOTAL salary") are not deleted. How should I modify the If (cell.value) = "Total" line? In order to delete those cells as well.

Comment: ... change your line of code: `If (cell.Value) = "TOTAL" Then` to `If InStr(1, UCase(cell.Value), "TOTAL") > 0 Then` - That will look for the word "TOTAL" in each cell (with all letters in uppercase) - Hope this does it.

Comment: Glad it helped - I'll post it as an answer then and just accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon what we discussed above, here's what you're looking for:

```
  Sub Delete_Rows()      
  Dim RNG As Range, cell As Range, del As Range      
  Set RNG = Intersect(Range("A1:A5000"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

     For Each cell In RNG
        If InStr(1, UCase(cell.Value), "TOTAL") > 0 Then
           If del Is Nothing Then
              Set del = cell
           Else
              Set del = Union(del, cell)
           End If
        End If
     Next cell

  On Error Resume Next
  del.EntireRow.Delete

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Code using `AutoFilter` or `Find` would be much more efficient than a range loop.

This code from my article [Using Find and FindNext to efficiently delete any rows that contain specific text](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_2919-Using-Find-and-FindNext-to-efficiently-delete-any-rows-that-contain-specific-text.html).

```
Option Explicit

Const strText As String = "TOTAL"

Sub ColSearch_DelRows()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim cel2 As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim lAppCalc As Long

    'Get working range from user
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select range to search for " & strText, "User range selection", Columns("A").Address(0, 0), , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Application
        lAppCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'a) match string to entire cell, case insensitive
    'Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, , False)

    'b) match string to entire cell, case sensitive
    'Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, , True)

    'c)match string to part of cell, case insensititive
    Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , False)

    'd)match string to part of cell, case sensititive
    ' Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , True)

    'A range variable - rng2 - is used to store the range of cells that contain the string being searched for
    If Not cel1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = cel1
        strFirstAddress = cel1.Address
        Do
            Set cel1 = rng1.FindNext(cel1)
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2.EntireRow, cel1)
        Loop While strFirstAddress <> cel1.Address
    End If

    'Further processing of found range if required
    'This sample looks to delete rows that contain the text in StrText AND where column A contains "Duplicate"
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then rng2.EntireRow.Delete

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lAppCalc
    End With

End Sub
```